# k-map for a function with more than 4 inputs

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, karnaugh-map

For functions with more than 4 variables, the usual solution is to use a number  of 4-input K-map tables in parallel. I wonder why not use one table with more than 2 inputs per row or column as long as the set of variabes is coded in gray code. The cells will stil be adjascent

Comment: This may be a question better suited for math overflow, unless you have a specific question about programming.

Comment: [Here](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~thormae/lectures/ti1/code/karnaughmap/) you can find an online application which demonstrates the use of extended Karnaugh maps ([Mahoney maps](http://davidbonal.com/karnaugh-and-mahoney-map-methods-for-minimizing-boolean-expressions/)) suitable for up to eight variables.

Comment: You can just do [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-8/larger-5-6-variable-karnaugh-maps/)